# log out doesn't work properly?

Tags: support, bug, logout

If I use StackExchange -> log out. And then I click the big `log out` button on the subsequent log out page

[image]

I am logged out.

But when I click login and login via google then I am logged in without the necessity to provide password. I am using shared computer so I was expecting to be really logged out after clicking log out.

Is logout working as intended?

I logged originally in using my google account. I am on firefox. Of course I am not logged into my google account. I typed my google password only when I was logging int SE.

Comment: I believe the act of "logging with Google", logs you into Google and thereby into Stack Exchangge, but logging out of Stack Exchange only logs you out of Stack Exchange, but not Google.

Comment: Of course I am talking about SE. I was not using any google application within the browser I used to log into SE.

Comment: Did you click on the big Log Out button on the page that appears after clicking on the log out link in the drop down?   It does not log you out until then.  Works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, I did click that button. After that it "looks" that I am logged out. I can see "sign in", "log in" links. When I click log in and select google option I am logged in without providing my google credentials.

Comment: You are most definitely logged into your Google account. Once you click that "log in with Google" button, it's out of SE's hands. Google sees that you're already signed in and passes your credentials along to SE without requiring you to enter your password again.

Answer (score 4):

It is a general Single Sign On problem (or feature). You have three parts interested in your logging session : client, google (auth provider), and SE (service).

When you first come form a fresh browser, and ask an URL on SE, you are neithe authenticated to SE nor to Google.

- SE does not know you and asks you to authenticate
- you choose Google authentication :

  - SO *redirects* you to a google authentication site
  - you authenticate on Google (and get a cookie from there)
  - Google authentication site redirects you back to SO
  - SO asks for you to Google and gives you a session (and a cookie)

When you disconnect from SO (SE), SE destroys your session but cannot (and should not without breaking SSO contract) disconnect you from google

At that moment you are no longer connected to SO but still connected to Google

Then, you try again to connect again to SO, and say that you still want to use Google authentication

- SO *redirects* you to a google authentication site
- Google sees that you are already authenticated with it
- Google authentication site redirects you back to SO
- SO asks for you to Google and gives you a session (and a cookie)

A SSO system precisely aims to let you enter your credentials only once and then authenticate you on many services. Here it authenticates you successively to 2 services (even if both are in fact the same : SO).

Comment: I kind of understand but 1) can SE can do something about that? 2) can I do fully logout if I use public computer?

Comment: @Radek You *are* fully logged out from SE. Go log out of Google if that bothers you.

Comment: @ChrisHayes : Some SSO systems have an URL (often ending in `/logout` ...) for explicit disconnect. A good practice for a service application is to do a redirect to that URL when they receive an explicit disconnection request. But I do not know the Google disconnect procedure, and IMHO the question should then be an explicit feature request.